# Setting a label to a value in Swift on XCode?

Tags: ios, swift

I understand it’s rather basic, but I’m only trying to get a grasp on basic functions.

I have produced some code by partially my own knowledge and partial bits from different guides.

I am not getting any errors, but the label is not displaying itself as “Text”. I believe it’s to do with the order/place my code is put.

Please help explain how I can fix this!

Please note as well:

- I have just a single label called myLabel (named under the document section of my the identity inspector
- It is has the text “Loaded” put into it already when I put it in.
- I have no other code anywhere, only the default new project code.
- I renamed the ViewController to ViewManager to avoid a class error.

[First image: This is the image just so you know the location and other bits. I’ll attach the code too:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTDXa.jpg)

[Second image: What I get, with no errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6a6t.png)

[Third image: My main storyboard file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhtGP.jpg)

And now it in code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
   @IBAction func labelSet() {
       myLabel.text = "Text"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your code is inside a function (`func`), but nothing seems to call it. Also, it's inside a `IBAction`, which usually expect a User Action (like a "touch"). if you want you text to be `"Text"` at "launch", add the code `myLabel.text = ...` inside `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how to use this info in the code? Where do I add the viewDidLoad and how would I call the functions as it says no expressions on top level.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the `IBAction` is connected to `Touch Up Inside` in Interface Builder.
2. Change the signature of the `IBAction` to

   ```
   @IBAction func labelSet(_ sender: UIButton) {
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `func labelSet()` isn't called anywhere. Neither in the Storyboard nor elsewhere.

You can call it in `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelSet()
    }
```

Alternatively call it after the label has loaded.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            labelSet()
        }
    }
```